# In SQL Server create a role that has all the rights except for a few tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, roles

I want to create an SQL server database role that is exact copy of db_owner role but should not have access to a few tables.

In short I want to do something like this:

1. Create a role which is clone of db_owner
2. Revoke few tables from that role

Is that possible? If yes the how? if no then what is the alternative way?

Comment: Why not give them the `db_owner` role and then another role that has `DENY` on the tables?

Comment: See: [DENY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you @Larnu your suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to create an SQL server database role that is exact copy of db_owner role but should not have access to a few tables. ... Is that possible?

No. db_owner has too many administrative privileges for you to prevent access to a few tables.  If you want a user to that has access to all the current and future objects in a database except a few, you *can* do that, using database-level GRANT and [DENY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/deny-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> DENY
>
> Denies a permission to a principal. Prevents that principal from
>   inheriting the permission through its group or role memberships. DENY
>   takes precedence over all permissions, except that DENY does not apply
>   to object owners or members of the sysadmin fixed server role.
>   Security Note Members of the sysadmin fixed server role and object
>   owners cannot be denied permissions.

eg:

```
create role foo

grant select, insert, update, delete, execute to foo --grant on whole database

deny select, insert, update, delete on dbo.secret to foo  --deny on a single object
deny select, insert, update, delete, execute on schema::admin to foo ----deny on a whole schema
```